# Logistic regression: Fisher's scoring iterations do not match the selected iterations in glm

Tags: r, regression, logistic, irls, fisher-scoring

it happened to me that in a logistic regression in R with `glm` the Fisher scoring iterations in the output are less than the iterations selected with the argument `control=glm.control(maxit=25)` in `glm` itself.

I see this as the effect of divergence in the iteratively reweighted least
squares algorithm behind `glm`.

My question is: under which criteria does `glm` stop the iterations and provides with a partial output? I was thinking about something like "when the new coefficients-old coefficients < epsilon, then STOP". Is this the case? If not, what does make `glm` stop?
Thanks,
Avitus

Comment: Hi @Avitus: The [help page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.control.html) of `glm.control` says it: there you can specify an `epsilon` and the iterations converges when $|dev-dev_{old}|/(dev + 0.1) < \epsilon$. "dev" means Deviance. The `maxit` option specifies the *maximum* number of iterations. If the algorithm hasn't converged after `maxit` iterations, the partial output is given as well as an error message.

Comment: Hi @COOLSerdash: your comment is actually an answer :-) I find it very helpful, thanks. One short silly question: what is the Deviance in glm.control? Is it the Deviance in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_(statistics)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the Deviance. Maybe [this](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~jtaylo/courses/stats203/notes/glmI.pdf) and [this](http://people.bath.ac.uk/sw283/mgcv/tampere/glm.pdf) will clarify Deviance further?

Comment: @COOLSerdash: COOL links! Thank you very much. All I need now is to think about the *choice* of Deviance as parameter to stop or continue the iterations and gently ask you to edit your comment above into a question to upvote it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `glm.control` you can specify a positive $\epsilon$ which is used to decide whether the algorithm has converged or not. The [documentation page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.control.html) of `glm.control` states that the algorithm converges if

$$
\frac{|dev - dev_{old}|}{(|dev| + 0.1)} < \epsilon
$$
Where "dev" means [Deviance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_%28statistics%29). These three resources maybe helpful in clarifying Deviance: [first](http://people.stat.sfu.ca/~raltman/stat402/402L11.pdf), [second](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~jtaylo/courses/stats203/notes/glmI.pdf), [third](http://people.bath.ac.uk/sw283/mgcv/tampere/glm.pdf).